# Is there any way to configure git to lock a file when a user work on it?

Tags: git, version-control, tfs

In TFS, when a user work on a class, other user can't work on it. Is there any configuration for git to do like this work or not?

Comment: Locking files in a *Distributed* VCS? :(

Comment: you are right, I had forgotten. thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Such a feature would go entirely *against* the distributed principle of Git.

In my experience, if you have two people working on the same file then one of two things will happen when you go to merge:

1. There are no merge conflicts because you have been working on separate areas of the code. Carry on. This is the usual case.
2. There are merge conflicts, and you must resolve them manually. **Communication between the two committers is usually essential.**

Answer (score 1):

No, that's totally Git, that's why for better pratices we should do frequent commits and take pulls to update our repository.

Any conflicts while merging the code should be resolved after checking for previous commits on same line of code and needs a communication.

Answer (score 0):

Having said all that,

[Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)
is an extension that will let you impose fine grained access control on your repos and files.